# Which hosting will let me execute my own EXE with PHP?

Tags: windows, php, hosting

I have a task that PHP (or any server-side scripting language) isn't practical for. It involves a lot of file I/O, processing, etc. and it will execute a lot faster using the program I made in C instead of PHP.

Do any hosts allow you to upload your own EXE files and run them on the server using PHP's exec, shell_exec, etc. functions?

Do you need a dedicated server to do this?

Also, I don't know if Facebook's PHP HipHop is out yet, but I really don't want to use that.

Answer (score 1):

You probably will need a dedicated server to do such a thing. Typically the exec function is disabled for obvious security reasons; a shared server would not want an executable such as yours eating tons of CPU time for everyone else.

Perhaps look into cloud hosting, such as [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/)? This way you could start up your own virtual private server and run your application in its ideal environment. Also since you said "EXE" I assume it's a Windows application, and you can indeed run a Windows environment on EC2, whereas most PHP hosts run Linux machines.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you write a CGI script in C and compile it. You could then take advantage of the speed of a compiled script and still keep in a format that the host is comfortable with.

Comment: You could even make it a PHP extension or a webserver module if the overhead of `CreateProcess()`  is too much for you.

Answer (score 0):

Nearly Free Speech says that C/C++ is welcome:  [CGI Support](https://www.nearlyfreespeech.net/about/faq#CGISupport).  It's also a great service and very cheap -- even for shared hosting.

If you want a dedicated virtual server, Slicehost, Rimu, and Linode are far cheaper than EC2 if scaling isn't a big issue for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider getting a VPS hosting. They're cheaper than dedicated hosting and you pretty much can do whatever you want within your VM sandbox.